# Add Trick Play feature with AVPlayerViewController in Swift

Tags: swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer, avplayerview

I implemented a video player function with `AVPlayer` in Swift 3.
Currently, I can play the video well. 
I would like to add the feature of "**Trick Play**" with the **speed of** ***2x,3x,4x***.
However, I didn't find anything googling. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
playerViewController.player!.rate = 2  // 3, 4 etc
```

Comment: I added your code but not work. I also added this code, still the same (not work)
vlcMediaPlayer.fastForward(atRate: 2.00)

Comment: Can you add some code to your answer to show what you've tried?

Comment: func btnTrickPlay(_ atRate: Float!){
if(atRate == 2.0){
            
           
            vlcMediaPlayer.rate = 2
            
        }
}